# Connect to 2 different Access tables with OleDb in one select statement. C# MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oledb, jet

Ok, this has been racking my brain, and I have tried EVERYTHING. Including combing this site, google, everywhere. I'm trying to connect to 2 different Access database tables (one named PhoneList and one named Employee) from one database (My HR.mdb) in MVC C# and I was hoping to be able to do it in one SELECT statement. The reason I'm doing that is because I want to populate a grid from one table and a label from another. I'm using Grid.Mvc here: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gridmvc Now, the grid is populating good but when I mess with the SELECT statement it starts breaking things. I'll comment in my code so you guys can see what I'm talking about. Oh and I've tried using UNION, UNION ALL and everything to no avail. I am OUT of options at this point. Believe me when I say I am NOT a database guy. So I know the code is wrong and/or probably not the most best/efficient way to do this. So please go easy on me. (-: Oh, and I'll probably have more than one question. First, my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
{
    var model = new List<Contact>();
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyHR"].ToString();
   //string SqlString = "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Employee";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name FROM Employee", conn))
        {
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", "FirstName");
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", "LastName");

            using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string name = string.Empty;
                    var contact = new Contact();
                    name = rdr["First_Name"].ToString() + " " + rdr["Last_Name"].ToString();
                    contact.UserName = name;
                    model.Add(contact);
                }
            }
        }
        using (OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PhoneList", conn))
        {
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", "First Name");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", "Last Name");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extension", "Extension");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMail", "EMail");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", "Department");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supervisor", "Supervisor");
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorEntension", "Supervisor Extension");

            using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var contact = new Contact();
                    contact.First = rdr["First"].ToString();
                    contact.Last = rdr["Last"].ToString();
                    contact.Extension = rdr["Extension"].ToString();
                    contact.EMail = rdr["EMail"].ToString();
                    contact.Department = rdr["Department"].ToString();
                    contact.Supervisor = rdr["Supervisor"].ToString();
                    contact.SupervisorEntension = rdr["SupervisorEntension"].ToString();
                    model.Add(contact);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

My Model code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Contact_Page.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }//For the label

        public string First { get; set; }

        public string Last { get; set; }

        public string Extension { get; set; }

        public string EMail { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string Supervisor { get; set; }

        public string SupervisorEntension { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Contact_Page.Models.Contact><=I can comment out to use label and not grid.
@*@model Contact_Page.Models.Contact*@<=I can comment out to use grid and not label.
@using GridMvc.Html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee Dashboard and their roles.";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <nav class="navbar navbar-xs navbar-inverse">
    <!--Some more HTML stuff...-->
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName) or @Html.Label()
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.First).Titled("First Name").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Last).Titled("Last Name").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Extension).Titled("Extension").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.EMail).Titled("EMail").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Department).Titled("Department").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.Supervisor).Titled("Supervisor").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.SupervisorEntension).Titled("Supervisor Extension").SetWidth(50).Filterable(true);
                    }).WithPaging(10)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/container-->
}
```

Ok, now for my second question concerning the label. If I comment out the first line `@model IEnumerable<Contact_Page.Models.Contact>` the Html.Label control doesn't give the red squiggly, but I can't use the grid control. If I comment out `@model Contact_Page.Models.Contact` and uncomment the other one, I can use the grid but not the label. I tried to get around this by using a plain-old HTML label like this: `<label id="UserName"></label>` but no success. Any thoughts guys? One more thing, incase anyone is wondering. The reason I'm trying to connect to the Employee table in the first place, is to just pull the First_Name and Last_Name from there and put it in my label at the top of my page so whoever is on this (intranet site, not internet site) will see their name. This will NOT be an outward facing site. Internal only. And in this particular table, when I open it in Server Explorer I noticed it would only display my information because it contains sensitive information like SSN and birthdate. I think our DBA has it locked down so I could only see my information, probably a permissions thing. Which is fine with me. So I thought "hey I'll grab First Name and Last Name from there and put it in a label." So, is this possible to do? I saw a lot of examples online of connected SELECT statements but nothing worked for me. Oh, and when I put a breakpoint on here:

```
name = reader["First_Name"].ToString() + " " + reader["Last_Name"].ToString();
contact.UserName = name;
```

I can see my first and last name from the Employee table, but it won't populate the label. If anyone could help me with some working code I would MOST certainly appreciate it. Thanks guys. Sorry this was so long.

Comment: The goal of a good question is not to dump your entire code base or all your functionality into [so]. Instead create an [mcve] which illustrates just the problem you are having. See also [ask].

Comment: Yes @Igor I do apologize for that, as I said, "sorry this was so long." I just wanted everyone to see what I have been trying already. I've seen posts on here where there was almost as much code posted. I didn't think it was really all that much. Its just that, all the code that I posted is relevant to my question.

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me. Some people post nothing.

Comment: Exactly @Ciarán, there was a reason I posted all that code. I didn't want to leave anything out so folks could see what I've been trying so far. Thank you. Honestly I didn't think it was _all that_ much code. (-:

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Actually @FrancescoB. I have something working; however I don't know if it's the right way to do it. And it's still not populating my label, although it is pulling my First and Last Name from that Employee database. Please see my controller code edit above.